# FFMPEG not able to extract thumbnails of images larger than .6 MB

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "imageLarge.jpg" -y -f mjpeg -s 72x92 -vframes 1 -an thumbnail7292.jpg
```

We are using this command to generate thumbnails of image files using FFmpeg but found that it is not able to generate thumbnails of files larger than .6 MB can somebody suggest something on this.

Comment: the error that it generates is swScaler: Compile time max width is 2048 change VOF/VOFW and recompile
Cannot get resampling context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what exactly the problem with `ffmpeg` is, but in any case I'd recommend using the `convert` utility from [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php?ImageMagick=3ppbscs65dpe8sjdrvrvbiqik0).  It's much simpler:

```
convert imageLarge.jpg -resize 72x92 thumbnail7292.jpg
```

If you give a description of the **actual error**, then more people will be able to help you.

**EDIT**

The OP's error is:

```
swScaler: Compile time max width is 2048  
change VOF/VOFW and recompile
Cannot get resampling context
```

It's quite clear what the problem is.  Your JPEG files are too big for your current build of `ffmpeg`.  You will have to recompile `ffmpeg` or get a newer version if you want to work with larger images.

This is from `src/libswscale/swscale_internal.h` (version: FFmpeg SVN-r26402).

```
#if ARCH_X86
#define VOFW 5120
#else
#define VOFW 2048 // faster on PPC and not tested on others
#endif
```

That's the file you need to edit if you want to change the limits.

**What version of ffmpeg are you using?**  This [problem seems to have been addressed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/+bug/443264) over a year ago.

If you don't want to rebuild `ffmpeg`, you could just use `convert`, like I originally advised.

Comment: swScaler: Compile time max width is 2048 change VOF/VOFW and recompile
Cannot get resampling context